# Why is my jqRouter.renderViewSuccess event handler called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am using [jq-router](https://github.com/muzammilkm/jq-router) in my app and this script is loaded dynamically based on the route name at the time. For some reason the event handler and therefore the `console.log` output is executed twice, no matter what I do. How do I stop this from happening? Or, why is this happening?

```
function init() {
   $(window).on('jqRouter.renderViewSuccess', function(e, viewRoute, route, params) {
       if(route.name == 'domains.single') {
          console.log(params.domain);
       }
   });
}
init();
```

Comment: The `jqRouter.renderViewSuccess` event is probably being fired 2x. You should look into that.

Comment: What could possibly be causing that? I've followed the implementation from GitHub on the plugin?

Comment: Or de-register the event handler after first run

Comment: Dunno @MitchEvans. I've never used jqRouter, but that seems the most obvious direction you need to look into.

Comment: @Geuis well I added a console.log before that call and it was only called once so you are right. Just have to track the issue down now.

Comment: If you can setup a replication of the issue on codepen.io that other people can look at, that might be a good next step too.

Comment: @Geuis I'm not able to duplicate the issues inside codepen.io. It never triggers the function.

Comment: It's only called twice on page refresh. If I navigate to the page from another page it does not get called twice.

Comment: @NickA how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @MitchEvans Are you sure `init()` isn't being called twice?

Comment: @Geuis Yes, I've added a console.log at the beginning of the function and it only shows up once.

Comment: @MitchEvans You can use the [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function: `$(window).on('jqRouter.renderViewSuccess', function(e, viewRoute, route, params) {if(route.name == 'domains.single') {console.log(params.domain);$(window).off('jqRouter.renderViewSuccess')}});`

Comment: @NickA that actually solved my problem! If you put it in an answer, I could mark it as solved and resolve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having trouble finding why the `jqRouter.renderViewSuccess` event is triggering twice you can instead remove the event handler after the first call to ensure it is only called once. You can do this using the jQuery [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function:

```
$(window).on('jqRouter.renderViewSuccess', function(e, viewRoute, route, params) {
    if(route.name == 'domains.single') {
        $(window).off('jqRouter.renderViewSuccess');
        console.log(params.domain);
    }
});
```

Comment: i remember .once method was in jq